# Why LocalDb needs user profile to be loaded?

Tags: sql-server, iis, localdb

I am playing with LocalDb from IIS. There are several instructions how to do that, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13768812/121968.

For what functionality LocalDb needs [the user profile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx) and [other specific requirements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership.aspx)?
(It is possible, for instance, to tweak the Local LocalDb not to call `SHGetKnownFolderPath`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalDB needs the user profile because it stores instances in "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances". Usually all guides tell you to connect to (localdb)\v11. What is "v11"? It's the name of an instance that represented by the folder "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11".

So in fact a LocalDB database is not "just" a single file, it is also a bunch of files stored in the instance folder. You can play with it. For example

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create LocalDBIsAHoax
SqlLocalDB.exe start LocalDBIsAHoax
sqlcmd -S (localdb)\LocalDBIsAHoax
1> create database MySuperDuperDB
2> go
1> :exit
dir "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\LocalDBIsAHoax"
```

I don't know a mean to make LocalDB place its instances in some other place.

Comment: So, LocalDb is not an alternative to SQLite.

Comment: It's a very poor alternative :(. I had a big optimism when I stumbled upon LocalDB at first, took me helluva a lot of time to figure out what it really is. As my Russian friend said: it is a cannon quickly adapted to small tasks of shooting sparrows. Because of the particular design it still has a huge iron gun carriage, requires a minimum 10 kg TNT payload, and it's recommended to shoot it in desolated places at the groups of sparrows of 1000 birds at once minimum.

Comment: You can in fact change where SqlLocalDB stores instance files by changing where %USERPROFILE% points to. Details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150238/localdb-change-sql-server-default-location/36867173#36867173. It's still a bit of a hack though.

Comment: @DanielSmith Did you read my answer? I literally said "I don't know a mean to make LocalDB place its instances in some other place **[than %USERPROFILE%\...]**". I.e. I specifically used %USERPROFILE% in the description. By your wording it seems like you are correcting me by saying exactly the same.

Comment: @facetus, not at all correcting you. Just stating that one technically can change where LocalDB stores its instances - admittedly in a hacky way. The idea is that it is possible to change a given environment variable for a single process, rather than machine-wide. I used this behavior to change %USERPROFILE% for the currently running process in order to change where LocalDB files were stored. This was for automated system tests running on a build server, where we needed to store temp files in a different drive. I found that this approach worked very well for this purpose. Cheers.

Comment: @DanielSmith Peace. I think I overreacted. Pandemic fatigue, I guess.