# Access is denied while trying to migrate EntityFramework6 mdf file - wrong path

Tags: .net, entity-framework, database-migration

I'm trying to play around with EntityFramework6. I'm using a code first approach, and I've created a database in my projectfolder/bin/debug/SchoolContext.mdf. The database has the proper tables when created and I'm also capable of adding data to it.

I reached a point in the tutorial where I can use migration to update the field. So I enabled the migrations from package manager, removed a field from a table and generated the migration by using `Add-Migration MigrationName`. The migration is generated, but when I try to run it by using `Update-Database`, I get the following:

```
CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\SchoolContext.mdf'.
```

...

The problem is that it is looking for the mdf file in the wrong path. I've tried to find how to solve this, but I couldn't.

The right path would be: `C:\Users\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Test2\Test2\bin\Debug\SchoolContext.mdf`

Here is my auto generated App.config file + my modifications of adding a connection string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bcsfdadsa56145" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|SchoolContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I do set the `DataDirectory` in the configuration file:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Test2.Data.SchoolContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
...
```

Comment: Are you sure that Configuration is istantiated? I'm asking it because of internal. Are you specifying it on `Database.SetInitializer`?

Comment: My experience with this whole migration and database in c# is limited. I don t recall using set initializer anywhere, but if I put a breakpoint in the configuration and I run the project it is stopped.

Comment: I think that the DataDirectory is not the right way. I don't know your requirements but you can also create a context specifying a connection or in several other ways. Check also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440405/entity-framework-6-set-connection-string-runtime

Comment: @bubi you can take a look here https://github.com/iDaniel/WPFTest. I've tried few things so there aren't many files.

Answer (score 1):

Code First allows you to stop using file path based connection strings in favour of much simpler connection strings that use a database name:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="SchoolContext"  
         connectionString="Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=School;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

You don't need to configure the path of the database, you just need the database name. You can remove the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData()` code from your `Configuration` class.

A simple way to make sure that the right connection string is used by your application runtime and also at design time by the Package Manager Console: your `DbContext` class should have a parameterless constructor that invokes the base constructor with the connection string name in your `app.config` file:

```
public MyDbContext() : base("SchoolContext") 
{ ... }
```

This is the easiest way to specify the connection data. EF 6 provides other ways to do it, as explained [in this msdn reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx).

And where will your database file be stored? It doesn't really matter anymore. [This page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database/) explains it. But be aware that `LocalDB` is not intended to be used in production systems, only in development environments.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was specifying the file path so the database is saved within the app folder. With your configuration the file will be saved in `C:\Users\yourusername` and I don't want that.

Comment: I see your point. Then you can try setting your `LocalDB` default path to a different place than your user profile with the `SQLLocalDB`command tool. Note that this will change the path for every other project too, so it would be better to specify a folder out of your specific project, something like `C:\Users\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Databases` (perhaps you don't want that). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150238/localdb-change-sql-server-default-location) contains the detailed explanation.

Comment: Another thing to try: when running `Update-Database` provide the specific connection string in the parameter `-ConnectionString`. I'm not sure that it would get the `|DataDirectory|` configuration, you may have to replace that part with the real path.