# Publish amsx Web service Into IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem when publishing my web service apps in IIS 8. My apps can't connect to my database.
[Picture when Running in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ReQi.png)

I tried publishing in IIS express via Visual Studio and it works.
[Picture when Running in IIS express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tuvh.png)

This is my connection string:

```
private const String connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|mfg_t_db.mdf;";
```

I am using visual studio 2013, Win 8.1 and SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Please don't post a wall of code as an image.

Comment: oh i am sorry @Teepeemm, it is my first time.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises when you try to *create* a database under `(LocalDB)` in one account, then *access* the database from another account - in this case, IIS's application pool account.

One solution is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761518/how-to-start-an-sql-server-localdb-via-iis) - using the same account for creation and access. This should be fine for development, but is not recommended for production.